# Raspberry pi + Qt cannot create an instance of QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qpixmap

I have written some program in Qt on Windows PC and now trying to recompile it on a Raspberry Pi. The problem I'm facing with, is the following:
There are some images to be loaded. These images shall be saved in a **QMap<int, QPixmap>**.
During loading of an Image, I'm creating an instance of **QPixmap** object, but it fails with **"Segmentation fault"**

```
//****************************************//
QMap<int, QPixmap> deviceImages;
//****************************************//
void MainWindow::loadImages(MainWindow *ui)
{
    int index = 0;
    QString ImagesPath = QDir(".").absolutePath() + "/Images/";
    QDir Image_Dir(ImagesPath);
    qDebug() << Image_Dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files);
    for(const QFileInfo &fileInfo : Image_Dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files))
    {
        if(fileInfo.suffix() == "png")
        {
            QString fileName = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
            QPixmap *image = new QPixmap(); // Segmentation Fault here
            if(image->load(fileName))
            {
                deviceImages.insert(index++, *image);
            }
        }
    }
    ui->success = QPixmap(ImagesPath + "/SlotAnimation/success.png");
    ui->warning= QPixmap(ImagesPath + "/SlotAnimation/warning.png");
    ui->safety= QPixmap(ImagesPath + "/SlotAnimation/safety.png");
    ui->notConnected = QPixmap(ImagesPath + "/SlotAnimation/notConnected.png");
}
```

I have tried some other variants to load a QPixmap, but it always causes a Segmentation Fault:

- QPixmap *image = new QPixmap(); image->load(fileName)
- QPixmap image = Pixmap(fileName);
- QPixmap image = Pixmap(); image.load(fileName);

I have also tried to start the program as a SUDO, it has the same Problem.

[Code with the breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY1r4.png)

[Effect after a step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp3rN.png)

Could someone explain where is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the actual stack trace in your debugger? It looks like it is pointing to `QObject::thread`, which has nothing to do with QPixmap.

Comment: Off topic but... the code shown leaks a `QPixmap` on every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: **Unrelated:** `QPixmap` is meant for showing image on screen purposes. I you want to store images, to operate on them/process them, etc... you should use `QImage` instead.

Comment: You should use `QPixmap` (or `QImage`) instead of `QPixmap*`. The pointers are useless here (except to leak memory since you lose track of the pointers :p).

Comment: FYI: _QPixmap objects can be passed around by value since the QPixmap class uses implicit data sharing._ (from [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html#details))

Comment: Also, it's unclear from your question (as pointed out, the actual stack trace will be more useful - much more than a *breakpoint image*), but if your the function *does* involve threading, then remember that Qt classes (especially GUI related ones) are [*not* thread-safe nor reentrant by default, unless explicitly declared](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-reentrancy.html). QPixmap is an interesting beast, as some platform plugins *do* allow threaded pixmaps, meaning that, unless you're completely sure about the environment of your platform(s), you shall never create/access them in external threads.

Comment: Did you try a minimum example? Just a main function and instantiate QPixmap. How much gpu mem did you assign? How large the image?